# Cyrus: In practical terms, how do end users administer their shared mailboxes?

Tags: imap, thunderbird, cyrus

Let's say we have four customer service reps: Billy, Bob, Joe, and Tom. Tom is the department manager. There's a shared Customer Service mailbox on the Cyrus server that they all have access to. Tom, as the manager also has administrative privileges for the shared mailbox.

They decide they want to create sub-folders a certain way, and Tom creates them. They're all running Thunderbird, so Tom right-clicks the main folder and chooses "New Subfolder".

Now Tom has the Subfolders he needs and the other sales reps have... nothing! Because Cyrus created the Subfolders giving Tom "Full Access" permissions, and everyone else gets no access.

So how does Tom give the other reps in his department access to the new folders?

As far as Cyrus is concerned, Tom has permission to grant others access to his new mailboxes- But as far as I can tell, there's no option in Thunderbird for granting mailbox permissions.

An IT staff member should not have to receive a support request every time someone wants to add a Subfolder to a shared mailbox. That's why we make certain users into mailbox admins in the first place!

But asking (non-technical) users to SSH into an IMAP server to run cyradm seems like a bad idea too.

Certainly someone has found a solution for this dilemma. Perhaps a Thunderbird extension for setting Cyrus permissions? Or something like umask that forces subfolders to have identical permissions to their parents on creation?

And related, what about Sieve configuration? Is there anyway that can be done from the client machine too?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

What version of cyrus are you running?  I've run a few different versions, and subfolders have always inherited permissions from their parent.

Here is a thunderbird ACL extension:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/imap-acl-extension/

Thunderbird also has a sieve extension, but it requires that you know the sieve language.  We use [Sogo](http://www.scalableogo.org/) for webmail which gives sieve gui, vacation messages, acl editing, etc.

Squirrel mail also has a sieve gui plugin.